# Did fwrite/fread(3) offer different "multiple items" behavior on different platforms historically?

Tags: c, posix, history, stdio

The  `fread(3)` and `fwrite(3)` have an extra parameter for a variable number of items. So a typical write often has a hardcoded count when all it has is a char buffer to begin with e.g. `fwrite(data, len, 1, stdout)`.

What is the point of this parameter? Was this always just a convenience "let the system do the multiplication" thing kind of like `calloc(3)` or did some historical operating systems and/or storage devices have special handling for individual items written?

Fueling my curiosity here is that I stumbled across some IBM z/OS documentation for [their `fwrite()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/fwrite.htm) which makes something of a distinction between "record I/O output" and "block I/O output" and talks about how each item could get truncated past a certain length — making me wonder if the item count parameter used to map to, say, separate physical punchcards — or at least maybe data could get written behind the scenes using ASCII "record separator" characters or whatever.

For contrast, the [POSIX fwrite spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) just outright says:

> For each object, size calls shall be made to the `fputc()` function, taking the values (in order) from an array of unsigned char exactly overlaying the object.

Which invites the question of why `fwrite` didn't just take in a `const uint8_t*` buffer and an overall `size_t` total length in the first place like `write(2)` does.

Comment: I considered posting this to Retrocomputing.SE instead, but since at least in theory "questions about earlier versions of a current machine or OS" are 
still listed as **off**-topic there (https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it seemed reasonable to try here first. Personally [based on what gets discussed here vs. here in practice] I feel this would be a better fit over there and if any moderators here agree, feel free to migrate!

Comment: I think that this is perfectly on-topic, as stdio first appeared on Unix. But then I'm a policy-enforced, not a policy-enforcer here. Take my answer as a comment (which would've been, if the format of this site were less stupid and allowed for proper formatting in comments and proper discussion threads).

Comment: And by seeming coincidence, https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16633/1932 . (-:

Comment: @JdeBP which doesn't have any real answer, either.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could gather, those functions first appeared in Unix version 7, and in that first [implementation](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/libc/stdio/rdwr.c), only `fwrite` did something special: it checked the error flag of the stream after writing each `size` block of data, instead of checking the return value of `putc`, as `fread` did with `getc`. But it doesn't look like that had any practical effects, beside wasting some extra cycles in case of i/o error.

Since both `putc` and `ferror` were simple macros, I don't think that `fwrite(b, large_val, 1, f)` was much faster than `fwrite(b, 1, large_val, f)` even then.

```
fwrite(ptr, size, count, iop)
unsigned size, count;
register char *ptr;
register FILE *iop;
{
        register unsigned s;
        unsigned ndone;

        ndone = 0;
        if (size)
        for (; ndone<count; ndone++) {
                s = size;
                do {
                        putc(*ptr++, iop);
                } while (--s);
                if (ferror(iop))
                        break;
        }
        return(ndone);
}
```